# Google Analytics virtual page for AJAX goal tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've got checkform which is triggered upon form submission below.

```
function checkform() {

    if (!document.getElementById('terms').checked) {
        alert('Read terms of use');
        return false;
    }

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/subscribe-successful']);
    return true;

}
```

I've also put trackPageview after if checked statement so if validation goes through, the `gaq.push` gets executed.

Also Google Analytics code itself is above this code so it's loaded before and I've got goal set up as `/subscribe-successful`

Is this the right way to track AJAX based goals?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, though keep in mind Google Analytics will now think your visitor is on that page for its visitor flow and time-on-page tracking.

I prefer using event tracking for things that don't involve navigating away from the page, like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Subscribe', 'Success']);
```

That will let you track successful subscriptions in Analytics without changing the visitor's URL. (And failures for that matter, if you want to track that.)

There are times when a virtual URL (your solution) is better, such as when the page content has changed fundamentally so that it's not effectively the same page anymore. It's up to you to decide which one this is.

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide for info on tracking events.

Comment: Hi, I've tested my code but it seems I'm not getting goal conversions when I check in Google Analytics? Is it instant result or do I have to wait at least a day to see the results?

Comment: You have to wait a day. Hopefully it should be there now.

Comment: Do you put this on the onclick or a button or input?

Comment: StevieG: I'm not sure what you're asking. You'd put code like that wherever you want to record an event happening. If you want to record an event whenever a button is clicked, then sure you'd put it in onclick or (better) its 'click' event handler.